# Using multiple buttons within dialog box with intents to change text of main button

Tags: java, android, android-intent, dialog

i am in a pickle at the moment to how to approach making 3 buttons within a single dialog box make the option selected change the text of the button used to show the dialog box, so far only managed to get option3 to work as i suppose its the last intent so the only button that works would be the button for option3

here is the code im trying to pass to the main button from the dialog

```
public class LabelDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
private Button option1, option2, option3;
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.label_dialog, null);

    builder.setView(view);
    //option 1 and 2
    option3 = view.findViewById(R.id.label_lecturebtn);
    option3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String option3 = "Lecture";
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(getContext(), AddTask.class);
            intent3.putExtra("lecture", option3);
            startActivity(intent3);
            dismiss();
        }
    });
```

and the main code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//...

    label_button = findViewById(R.id.button_labels);
    label_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openDialog();
        }
    });

    checkLabelResult();
}
public void openDialog() {  //Labels dialog
    //code to open dialog
}

public void checkLabelResult() {
    //intents 1 and 2, same format as 3 but keys changed accordingly

    Intent intent3 = getIntent();
    String option3 = intent3.getStringExtra("lecture");
    label_button.setText(option3);
}
```

Code for Option 1

```
option1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String option1 = "Important";
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AddTask.class);
            intent.putExtra("important", option1);
            startActivity(intent);
            dismiss();
        }
```

Code for Option 2

```
option2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String option2 = "To Do";
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getContext(), AddTask.class);
            intent2.putExtra("to do", option2);
            startActivity(intent2);
            dismiss();
        }
```

Comment: Please post the rest of the code (for options 1 and 2)

Comment: Hi David, code for option 1 and 2 has been posted, apologies for the very late update

Comment: In your code for option 1, you set the click listener on `option2`. This isn't correct.

Comment: Also, how do you set the values of `option1` and `option2`? Maybe you are setting those to the wrong buttons in the layout.

Comment: sorry but could you explain further what do you mean by setting the values to the wrong buttons?

Comment: maybe you do `option1 = findViewById(R.id.wrong_view_id)`?

Comment: just checked, its option1 = view.findViewById(R.id.label_imptbtn);, the correct id for option1

Comment: Well, I don't have any more ideas. Add debug logging, set breakpoints and see what happens